# Symmetric and Asymmetric Keys Encryption Question

Tags: public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I wanna ask about symmetric encryption (secret key) and asymmetric (public & private keys)
In your knowledge?

So my question is "How do you store the keys securely?"
I just saw this question and I feel confuse on it.
Is there more besides just these keys? like software, etc?
So does this mean my keys are vulnerable?
I'm preparing for a report and I need good ideas, if you have something to add it is welcome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this kind of question is off topic on SO, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In Public Key Cryptography the master key pair is tantamount to your identity, so you have to be extremely careful that it (specifically the master private key) is not compromised. The best way to achieve this is by storing your master private key in a secure separate location, and have a subkey on your main machine for regular use. Your day-to-day subkey is certified by your master key, so people know that it can be trusted. If your subkey is compromised then you can release the revocation certificate which you created in advance (!!! make sure you *do* create one) for that specific subkey.


In terms of how to protect your master private key,  I quote the Debian Wiki (https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys) at length because it always makes me smile:

> You should keep your private master key very, very safe. However, keeping all your keys extremely safe is inconvenient: every time you need to sign a new package upload, you need to copy the packages onto suitable portable media, go into your sub-basement, prove to the armed guards that you're you by using several methods of biometric and other identification, go through a deadly maze, feed the guard dogs the right kind of meat, and then finally open the safe, get out the signing laptop, and sign the packages. Then do the reverse to get back up to your Internet connection for uploading the packages.

Storing an important key
===================
The humourous routine above specifically mentions the master private key because of how important that key is to public key cryptography, but it is also applicable to the storage of any important secret including the storage of a secret key for symmetrical encryption. 


In asymmetric encryption because you won't often need to use the master private key I would suggest transferring it to physical media (CD/USB stick/paper! etc) then storing this media somewhere very safe, ideally 'offsite' in a different location from where you live/work, maybe with a close relation? For extra protection you could symetrically encrypt the physical media with your 'standard' 'easy' password which you will always remember in the future and which has probably been leaked on the Dark Web a few times. This extra step will mean that if someone picks up the CD and sticks it into a computer out of curiosity then they won't immediately know what is on it, thwarting some opportunist/unconnected attackers. 


You could employ some of the above for the storage of a symmetrical encryption secret key but if you will require frequent require access then it could be extremely inconvenient. Instead you should consider storing the key in a solution (a password manager for example) that requires multi-factor authentication for access (Wikipedia provides a good starting point for research into MFA - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication#Factors)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many online and offline secure vaults you may use to store your keys those vault will give you another dimension of security like password, multi factor authentication and even encryption of storage database.
However, there are some technologies like TPM to store cryptographic encryption keys on the CPU to take care of securing the encryption keys from side channel attack.
Long story short, there is not 100% way of securing keys except to put them in a safe-box and throw it in the silent space and the no one even you can access those keys anymore, this is a tradeoff between availability and security the more secure the less available and vice versa